# Print integer number in RML report

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7, rml

I want to print integer number in RML report like 0,1,2 but I in RML report 0.00,1.00 and so on number is display.
I return and try to convert it in integer using type casting but same output return  in RML report.
please suggest me how to print integer number or remove fraction part in RML report.

Comment: You tell you've tried with a cast. Have you tried with this cast?: `[[  int(your_integer) ]]`

Comment: its working but if found one problem if 0 is found in value then nothing is print so what I do next ??

Comment: Try to put `[[ int(your_integer) or '0' ]]`

Comment: Thanks its working fine

Comment: I'm going to post the comment as an answer in order you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put `[[ int(your_integer) or '0' ]]`.

Regards.